# denoising algorithm for salt and pepper type noise

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'd like to denoise an image as the one below. It looks like salt and pepper noise coming from poor scanners. What class of algorithm would you recommend to use for this type of noise? (bonus point if it's easily done with opencv)

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I have tried the different means filtering algorithm in openCV like fastNlMeansDenoising and played with different values for the parameters but the results were not great. I feel there are some obvious algorithm like median filtering for those types of problem, but there are also probably much better ones as well for specifically "scanner-like noise on documents that contains text only (and some lines) and is black and white"

Comment: Then please show us what you have tried and how it works (or doesn't).  You will get much better responses if you have some vaguely working code.

Comment: and I would suggest trying a couple errosions followed by a couple of dilations.

Answer (score 3):

Among classical filters, median filtering is a filter of choice for that kind of noise. You can also try morphological filtering (dilation followed by erosion in this case I guess).

If you know how to implement it, an anisotropic diffusion process (in particular with an L1 data term, such as the TV-L1 denoising algorithm in the [Chambolle-Pock paper](https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~peyre/numerical-tour/tours/optim_5_primal_dual/)) is also interesting.

Finally, if you want a nice binary (black-and-white only) image, then you have to insert some binarization via thresholding at some point in your toolchain. My choice would be to do it either at the very beginning or at the very end of the processing chain.

Answer (score 1):

An MRF often works well for denoising. The paper [Text Identification in Noisy Document Images
Using Markov Random Field](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.58.3822&rep=rep1&type=pdf) should be useful. I don't think OpenCV has an MRF implementation, but you can find a good one [here](http://vision.csd.uwo.ca/code/) under Multi-label optimization , and you will want its [Python binding](http://peekaboo-vision.blogspot.com.au/2012/05/graphcuts-for-python-pygco.html).